# Appending td in tr and then in tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have the next code:

```js
var data_object =[{"data1":"DATA1","data2":"DATA2","data3":"DATA3"}]

var tr;
for (var ctr = 0; ctr < data_object.length; ctr++) {
  tr = $("<tr></tr>");
  tr.append("<td>" + data_object[ctr].data1 ? data_object[ctr].data1 : '' + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + data_object[ctr].data2 ? data_object[ctr].data2 : '' + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + data_object[ctr].data3 ? data_object[ctr].data3 : '' + "</td>");

  $('#tblAutoMatch tbody').append(tr)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblAutoMatch" class="table table-bordered" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center; width: 5%;">Data 1</th>
      <th class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center; width: 13%;">Data 2</th>
      <th class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center; width: 13%;">Data 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

However, there is a problem: Why is `td` not appended to `tr`? I only get text in the `tr`.

Comment: Can't concatenate with results of a ternary expression. Resolve the ternary outside of `.append()` and place the result inside the conacatenation.

Comment: @RandyCasburn or use parenthesis.... no need to move it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your expressions that use the ternary operator by parenthesis `(...)`, example:

```
tr.append("<td>" + (data_object[ctr].data1 ? data_object[ctr].data1 : '') + "</td>");
```

So, they are evaluated as you will expect. Otherwise your expression will be evaluated like this:

```
tr.append(("<td>" + data_object[ctr].data1) ? data_object[ctr].data1 : ('' + "</td>"));
```

And will be reduced to `data_object[ctr].data1` because `("<td>" + data_object[ctr].data1)` will be evaluated to `true`.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var data_object = [
      {"data1":"DATA1","data2":"DATA2","data3":"DATA3"}
    ];

    var tr;
    
    for (var ctr = 0; ctr < data_object.length; ctr++)
    {
        tr = $("<tr>");
        tr.append("<td>" + (data_object[ctr].data1 ? data_object[ctr].data1 : '') + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + (data_object[ctr].data2 ? data_object[ctr].data2 : '') + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + (data_object[ctr].data3 ? data_object[ctr].data3 : '') + "</td>");

        $('#tblAutoMatch tbody').append(tr)
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tblAutoMatch" class="table table-bordered" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center; width: 5%;">Data 1</th>
      <th class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center; width: 13%;">Data 2</th>
      <th class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center; width: 13%;">Data 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```